# Why did I get a "pop" spark at outlet?

Tags: electrical

I plugged a laptop charger/converter into a wall receptacle and got a "pop" spark, different from the arc caused by plugging in something that is ready to draw current. It tripped the circuit breaker. The charger was not connected to a laptop at the time.

I reset the breaker and plugged a plug-in tester into the receptacle--it showed everything normal, grounded, etcetera. The other receptacle of the pair continued to work fine.

What happened?? Is it safe to use?

Comment: Have you tried to plug the charger into a different outlet? The charger may have an internal short.

Comment: What kind of breaker was it? Was it an arc-fault (AFCI) breaker? If so that's your answer.

Comment: There are plenty of cheap/trashy transformers out there. Was yours an actual OEM version, or something else?

Comment: @Tester101 -- NAD -- the OP indicates that this is not the same arc as plugging something in that's going to draw current straightaway.

Comment: Thanks all! I will try the charger in a different outlet. (It's HP OEM.) The breaker isn't AFCI--good thought though. Is it possible that the charger had a stored charge of some kind that went to ground when I plugged it in? I don't know how a converter works.